# Seleniumwire webdriver.Remote SessionNotCreatedException -- seleniumwire doesn't work with updated selenium webdriver.Remote code

Tags: python, selenium, seleniumwire

I am having a problem with switching from selenium webdriver.Remote to seleniumwire webdriver.Remote. Everything works fine while I'm running code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Scraping(webdriver.Remote):
    """
    Class creates instance of webdriver with possibility to scrap info from fiat-like sites.
    """
    def __init__(self, url, command_executor=COMMAND_EXECUTOR,
                 teardown=False, time_=5):
        self.command_executor = command_executor
        self.teardown = teardown
        self.seleniumwire_options = {'addr': "127.0.0.1",
                                     'auto-config': False}
        self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
        self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'pl,pl_PL',
                                                              "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2})
        super(Scraping, self).__init__(command_executor=command_executor, options=self.chrome_options)
        self.implicitly_wait(time_)
        self.url = url
        self.get(url)
        self.switch_to.default_content()
```

But when I'm trying to switch to seleniumwire

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
...
    super(Scraping, self).__init__(command_executor=command_executor, options=self.chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=self.seleniumwire_options)
...
```

I got error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. New session request timed out
Host info: host: 'mine', ip: '192.168.21.3'
Build info: version: '4.5.0', revision: 'fe167b119a'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_341'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Stacktrace:
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.local.LocalNewSessionQueue.addToQueue (LocalNewSessionQueue.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.NewSessionQueue.lambda$new$0 (NewSessionQueue.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle (Route.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionqueue.NewSessionQueue.execute (NewSessionQueue.java:123)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute (SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute (Router.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.CheckOriginHeader.lambda$apply$0 (CheckOriginHeader.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.CheckContentTypeHeader.lambda$apply$0 (CheckContentTypeHeader.java:70)
    at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.lambda$apply$0 (EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.java:34)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$NestedRoute.handle (Route.java:270)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle (Route.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute (Route.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0 (AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0 (ErrorFilter.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0 (ErrorFilter.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute (Filter.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0 (SeleniumHandler.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)
```

I see that in this case driver.version is unknown, but since selenium is able to detect it I don't understand the problem. I have tried to change ip to grid ip (192.168.21.3), but it doesn't work as well.

**My question**
What should I change to make seleniumwire work with the same code as selenium